# Overload angle brackets in Haskell as inner product operator

Tags: haskell

I'm wondering whether I can overload angle brackets '<' and '>' something like:

```
data Vec a = Vec [Integer] deriving Show
let u = Vec [1, 2, 3]
let v = Vec [2, 4, 5]

<u, v> = inner product of u and v
```

I know I can overload '<&>' as operator like:

```
Vec u <&> Vec v = Vec $ zipWith(\x y -> x*y) u v
```

Comment: Although this is not an answer, there are a number of people that actually do not like the idea of *operator overloading* (and related concepts) at all. Since code becomes rather cryptic. If you read `f <$> xs` then it is hard to understand what that means, but `fmap f xs` already gives you a hint what you are doing. Personally I agree to some extend: if one writes `<u, v>` i need some additional knowledge what is going on, whereas `inner u v` actually gives a hint what it is dooing.

Comment: In principle, you could write your own QuasiQuoter, which allows you to define new syntax with almost total freedom, but that would require to code your own parser. I would advise against that.

Comment: Nitpick: there is no overloading involved in the `<&>` example. That is just a function definition, in which the name of the function happens to be `<&>`.

Comment: Also, you can't "decompose" `<&>` and interpret it as `<...>` somehow operating on `&`. It's just a 3-character operator name, with the brackets having no more meaning than any other characters you might use in an operator name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you can't really do this. Haskell isn't Agda. Haskell recognizes `()`, `[]`, and `{}` brackets only. `()` are used only for tuple types and grouping. `{}` are used for various syntactic purposes, none of which you have any control over. `[]` are generally used for lists. You can use `OverloadedLists` and/or `MonadComprehensions` to affect the way list syntax is interpreted, but only in limited ways that don't relate to what you request. There is no way to convince Haskell that `<` or `>` are brackets. The only think you could probably do would be to process your own syntax with Template Haskell, but that will add additional syntactic overhead of its own.